# Sync images/videos in drupal with alfresco content types

Tags: drupal, alfresco

I am working on integration of alfresco with drupal. I found the cmis drupal module.
where there is cmis sync module which can sync the content of drupal node to alfresco content type.
I want my alfresco to store my assets (images , videos etc). I want a module which allows me to sync my assets of drupal with alfresco content?

Can anyone suggest a workaround for it??
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

EDITWell, I have not checked what are the features avilable in the module you are using but I had previous experience of integrating Alfresco and Drupal.
What I had done is exposed Alfresco repository to Drupal via Webscripts, response from my webscripts are consumed by Drupal and rendering logic is resides in Drupal.

Now in your case if you want to use Alfresco contents in your Drupal site there are already Out of Box set of CMIS services available in Alfresco which will serve you the content from alfresco repository.For checking details regarding that you can refer following links

http://cmis.alfresco.com/

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/cmis/

I hope this will guide you. Let me know if any thing is not clear to you.

EDIT: just now checked this 
https://drupal.org/project/cmis
If you are using this as per description it should provide bidirectional sync of contents.

Comment: Hi actually I tried cmis module of drupal but it syncs only the text part not the attacments or image

Comment: In that case I think you need to do it your self by creating some patch.Are you getting other metadatas? Also are you able to fetch the associated images noderef or anyother useful info?

Answer (score 3):

The sync is meant to sync the body field from a page node into the content stream of an Alfresco node (and back). When we created the module originally we assumed that if you wanted to manage binary objects in Alfresco you'd just use the Alfresco interface to manage those instead of uploading those in Drupal and sync-ing them across.